# Python re matching fails to work for extened unicode range

Tags: python, unicode, python-re

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"[\u20000-\u2A6D6]+")

pat.match("Hello World!")
```

This will give us a result

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='Hello'>
```

But in fact, the input string here is fully ASCII which is not from the unicode range.

Is this expected? If so, how to compile those unicode range in practice?

Comment: `pat = re.compile(r"[\U00020000-\U0002A6D6]")` <- use `\U` when describing a character literal wider than two bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern currently describes a character class consisting of either `\u2000`, any character in the range `0-\u2A6D` or `6`.

For python character literals that are wider than 2 bytes, you need to use the escape sequence [`\U` with 8 hex digits](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code):

```
pat = re.compile(r"[\U00020000-\U0002A6D6]+")
```

Comment: Is this in their/any documentation? This is the first time I learn about this.

Comment: @Vimos [certainly](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (scroll down to the escape-sequence tables).